# Subscript under subset sign

Tags: symbols, subscripts

How can one achieve a sub-index and super-index over a subset sign, as in the following image:

[image]

I have not found any resources online. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\mathop{\subset}_{t=x}^{t=y}`  will give the limits layout you show in display math.

Comment: The simplest answer and it works

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\DeclareMathOperator*` from the `amsmath` package. That way you get the indices above and below only in display mode, not inline so the spacing between lines is not affected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\isubset}{\subset}

\begin{document}

\[
\isubset_{t=x}^{t=y} f(t,\vec x, \vec\alpha)
\]

Inline: $\isubset_{t=x}^{t=y} f(t,\vec x, \vec\alpha)$.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rotate `\bigcup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigsubset}{%
  \DOTSB\mathop{\bigsubsupset@{\bigcup}}\slimits@
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigsupset}{%
  \DOTSB\mathop{\bigsubsupset@{\bigcap}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigsubsupset@}[1]{\mathpalette\bigsubsupset@@{#1}}
\newcommand{\bigsubsupset@@}[2]{%
  \vphantom{\sum}% vertical space
  \vcenter{\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\m@th#1#2$}}}
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\else\,\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A
+
\sum_{t=x}^{t=y}f(t,\vec{x},\vec{a})
+
\bigsubset_{t=x}^{t=y}f(t,\vec{x},\vec{a})
+
\bigsupset_{t=x}^{t=y}f(t,\vec{x},\vec{a})
\]
\begin{center}
$
A
+
\sum_{t=x}^{t=y}f(t,\vec{x},\vec{a})
+
\bigsubset_{t=x}^{t=y}f(t,\vec{x},\vec{a})
+
\bigsupset_{t=x}^{t=y}f(t,\vec{x},\vec{a})
$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `\vphantom{\sum}` you'd get

[image]